# Confirm Box from within Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, firefox3.6, confirmation

I am having trouble getting the following code to work in FireFox (3.6.4), however, it works perfect in Chrome (5.0.375.70) and IE (8.0.7600.16385).

Operating system is Windows 7 32 Bit. 
Silverlight Version(4.0.50401.0)

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Confirm("Are you sure you would like to Remove this?")
```

As a matter of fact, it not only does not work in FireFox, but it pops up the dialog box, then you must end the FireFox process in order to continue working.  Has anyone else had this issue? Is there a fix?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I had the same problem with Firefox but you should be able to get around it by using Silverlight's MessageBox command with the optional MessageBoxButton.OKCancel flag.

```
MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
```